# Irreducibility in Function Fields

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, function-fields

I was reading a paper on Function Fields. There is a  statement like this. " Let $F \in F_q[t][x]$ here $x$ is a variable over $F_q[t]$and $deg_{x} F>0$ and $q$ is a power of $p$.
 Here author makes an assumption these $F$ are irreducible in $x$ and separable in $t$.

Now if I take $F = f(t)+x g(t)$, $f(t), g(t) \in F_q[t]$ are relatively prime polynomials this is a linear function in $x$ hence irreducible.

But if I take $F= f(t)+x^{2}g(t)$  what can be concluded? here $f(t) and $g(t)$ are relatively prime polynomials.

does it  factorize as $(\sqrt{f(t)}+ix\sqrt{g(t)})(\sqrt{f(t)}-ix\sqrt{g(t)})$ in $F_q[t]$.

Any one can please check the correctness of this. Thank you

Comment: There are several ways. Among others, Eisenstein's criterion applies with the obvious modification.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen,  can we be assured  of  $F_q[t]$ does not contain a square root of $f(t)$ and $g(t)$

Comment: No. But not all polynomials of the form $f(t)+x^2 g(t)$ are irreducible either. For example, $x^2-t^2$ obviously isn't. Didn't you say that the author *assumed* $F$ to be irreducible. So anything that follows may be false if  $F$ was reducible to begin with?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much.  I got it. Also you mentioned about Eisenstein criteria. Could you give a hint.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, how to use Eisenstein in function field case? for eg., the above,  its in F_q[t][x] I searched I do not find  any material, could you please help me.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen,  Is this argument  right? $f(t), g(t) \in F_q[t]$ with $deg(f(t), g(t))>0$ and $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are relatively prime polynomials. Then $f(t)+x^{2}g(t)$ is irreducible by Eisenstein criteria in $F_q[t][x]$?

Comment: No. Eisenstein's criterion states that if there exists an irreducible polynomial $p(t)\in F_q[t]$ such that $p(t)\mid a_i(t)$ for $i=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, $p(t)\nmid a_n(t)$, and $p(t)^2\nmid a_0(t)$ then
$$a_n(t)x^n+a_{n-1}(t)x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1(t)x+a_0(t)$$ is irreducible in $F_q[t][x]$. As in the case of $\Bbb{Z}[x]$, Eisenstein's criterion is **not** a general method for deciding irreducibility. It is **only a sufficient criterion** guaranteeing irreducibility. In general, determining irreducibility is relatively difficult. Not unlike determining whether some large integer is a prime or not.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you very very much.  could you please write this an answer.

Comment: No, I don't want to "copy" stuff straight out of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Generalization).